# PopupWindow is above status bar in some device

Tags: android, popupwindow, sony, nexus-s

Here is my code for show a `PopupWindow`

```
View rootView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(rootView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);
```

When I test it on `Samsung`, `Nexus` device it show **below** the status bar
However when I test it on `Sony` device it show **above** the status bar (like the image below)

So which device display correct or what I do wrong ?
Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve my problem by create a **temp** `View` at `top-left` (`topLeftView` in below code).
Then when I show the `PopupWindow`, I will show it at `(0, the y coordinate of topLeftView)` not `(0,0)`

```
View topLeftView = findViewById(R.id.top_left_View);
int topLeftPos[] = new int[2];
topLeftView.getLocationOnScreen(topLeftPos);

mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(topLeftView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, topLeftPos[1]);
```

I think this solution will work for all devices

Comment: It looks like the Android flavor in Sony devices calculate the top left corner as the physical top left corner while the Nexus and Samsung devices calculate the top left corner excluding the status bar.